# How to return top-n probability and its associated classes?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

In sklearn `predict_proba()` method, usually we only look at the one with highest probability. How can I output the probability for the top n classes (n>1)?

For example, the output from `predict_proba()` is like this, how can I return the highest 2 probabilities and its associate classes?

```
result_prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

return:

```
array([
   2.55420153e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   3.41739673e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.11688875e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 8.02579585e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 1.37978949e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 1.15640553e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 6.76391638e-02,
   9.06030431e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.56218448e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])
```

In this case, the classes with probability of `8.02579585e-01` and `6.76391638e-02` should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a Numpy question; you could use [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
import numpy as np
x =np.array([
   2.55420153e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   3.41739673e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.11688875e-05, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 8.02579585e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 1.37978949e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 1.15640553e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 6.76391638e-02,
   9.06030431e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 3.56218448e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
   0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00])

k = 2 # top-k
ind = np.argpartition(x, -k)[-k:]
x[ind]
```

Result:

```
array([0.06763916, 0.80257959])
```

as requested, while the respective classes are in `ind`:

```
ind
# array([27, 14])
```

Comment: Thanks, then how can i find the associated class of the two returns?